# Auto update graph when new data entry in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I make my website graph auto-update without reloading my .php page?
Let's say `ceeri.in/monitor` is my main page where the graph is, and data is coming into PHP pages `fllowdata1.php` and `fllowdata2.php` and the graph declared on the JS page.

Currently, I'm auto reloading the page but I'm trying to get the graph to update without having auto reload. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need to use Ajax

Comment: You can use AJAX to load the data in the background. If you want the server to push changes, you have to use a solution like socket.io (a standing connection between client and server).

Comment: where should i add Ajax in js pages or in my main page ??

Comment: You can do both, but I would create a js file, with my ajax code (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and add it to the pages that requires the ajax

Comment: Add it wherever you need it. If you don't understand how to use AJAX then I would suggest you study some tutorials and documentation before you go any further

Comment: oh.. thank you :) 
yeah i have to study about it something new to me..

Answer (score 0):

> **Php/Ajax example:**
>
> In this example you have index.html and record_count.php files
>
> **Here is the Code:**
>
> ```
> index.html contains the html code and javascript call to load record_count.php
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
>       function ()
>       {
>          $('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
>       }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
> </script>
>
> <body>
>      <div id="load_tweets"> </div>
> </body>
> ```
>
> and record_count.php has the php code
>
> ```
> <?php
> echo "some code or variable here";
> ?>
> ```
>
> you can change the javascript interval to suit your needs